# How do I set a dynamic datasource for ORM?

Tags: orm, coldfusion

ORM settings in Coldfusion application.cfc run before anything else runs (onapplicationstart, etc).  So how do you set a dynamic datasource (code before the ORM init) in application.cfc?  we can set it after and it re-points the ORM to a dynamic datasource, but that requires that the hardcoded datasource must be valid as well.  This is tenuous at best.

Here is an example:

```
<cfscript>
this.name = "someapp_#hash(cgi.http_host)#";
this.ormenabled = "true";
this.ormsettings = { cfclocation = "config/definitions", eventhandling = "true",datasource="STATICDATASOURCE" };
</cfscript>
```

If it's not specified in application.cfc scope then you get errors like "ORM is not configured for the current application."

We need to be able to get the datasource from a text file on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.datasource="YourDatasourceName";
```

Well, if you wanted to store a file, for this example we'll call it "datasource.xml" consisting of:

```
<dataSourceName>Name goes here</dataSourceName>
```

You can read it in with:

```
dataFile = fileRead("pathToFile/datasource.xml");
data = xmlParse(dataFile);
dataSourceName = data.dataSourceName.xmlText;

this.datasource=dataSourceName;
```

Answer (score 0):

ORM datasource just uses the default datasource if not defined.

Having said that, if you want to add / remove datasource dynamically, see Administrator API at: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fcf.html (available since CF8)

I'm not sure if you can re-set the `this.ormsettings.datasource` to something else at runtime (i.e. `onApplicationStart()`? or `onServerStart()`?), but many of the settings can be set again.  You may want to try it out.